# Can I import my own custom modules without using os.chdir()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been following the guide [here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-is-init-py-used-for.htm) for creating and importing your own custom modules, but I seem to be missing something.

So far, i have done:

1. I have the directory `C:\Users\Me\OneDrive\CustomModules\MathFunctions`.
2. Added `C:\Users\Me\OneDrive\CustomModules` to my system environment PATH.
3. Under `MathFunctions`, I have 2 files: `__init__.py` and `Functions.py`.

After starting Python, simply typing

```
from MathFunctions import Functions  # Doesn't work
```

as the guide shows doesn't work.

However, if I use the os.chdir() first, it works:

```
import os                                       # Works
os.chdir('C:/Users/Me/OneDrive/CustomModules')
from MathFunctions import Functions
```

Is there some way to avoid using os.chdir()? Or is that a necessary step every time?

Comment: use `sys.path.append('C:/Users/Me/OneDrive/CustomModules')` instead

Comment: You need to add the path to your package to your `PYTHONPATH`, not your normal `PATH` variable.